# Referencing in Overleaf

Tags: citing, natbib

Could you please tell me how to get this referencing style in Overleaf? No italic words, with full name and year after name.

Joel, Slemrod, 2007. Cheating ourselves: the economics of tax evasion. Journal of
Economic Perspectives, 21(1), 25–48.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX